# How to rewrite SQL query to Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to write this query in Laravel

```
Select * 
From table 
Where (column1 like '%value%' or column2 like '%value%') 
  and column3 > 0
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Class::where('coloumn1', $value1)->orWhere('column2', $value2)->andWhere('column3', '>', 0)->get();

Comment: @BradGoldsmith that wont work. check the answer i posted

Comment: @N69S I wasn't 100% sure thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Please format code as code (not as normal text).

Answer (score 2):

i'm assuming that the model class is `User`:

```
User::where(function($query) use ($value1, $value2) {
    $query->where('column1', 'like','%'.$value1.'%')
    ->orWhere('column2', 'like', '%'.$value2.'%');
})->where('column3','>', 0)
->get();
```

That how you do the parenthesis in `Eloquent`.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
Model::where('column3','>'0)
     ->where(function($result,$value1,$value2) {
         $result->where('column2' ,'LIKE','%'.$value2.'%')
        ->orWhere('column1' ,'LIKE','%'.$value1.'%');
    })->get(); //for multiple data
```

Comment: It will generate invalid query

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek how can you say that

Comment: This is unfortunately true. If you don't wrap first where and orWhere with additional where clause as showed in 1st answer, it will generate query `WHERE A OR B AND C` instead of `WHERE (A OR B) AND C` what might be very harmless in real application